# How to properly reseal shower tile

Tags: shower, tile, grout

I renovated a bathroom last year which includes a curbless shower.  I have few complaints. One of them is I think I didn't seal the shower grout well enough.  I have applied bottle/brush sealer a few times after the initial seal and I'm worried I just locked in the moisture that was in the grout lines.  My guess at how to do this right to reseal is:

1. clean the surface well
2. Use a Sealer and coating remover to remove all the old sealer
3. Let dry thoroughly with a dehumidifier in the bathroom for a few days
4. apply several coats of grout sealer over several days

[image]

Questions:

- Is this process correct?
- Should I be sealing the tiles also with something?

Comment: I removed the request for product recommendations as that is explicitly off topic. The rest of the question is excellent.

Comment: @FreeMan This probably isn't the best place for me to bring this up, (and I may be wrong) but I thought it was only shopping help that was off topic. There is even a tag called product-recommendation

Comment: @izzy A direct quote from the `Close` question dialog: "Questions seeking product or service recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve." Asking for a product category is OK, but the question asked what product do you recommend for the sealer. Where "sealer" is already a known category. Open to interpretation, I know, but I _believe_ this to be the general consensus of the community. I could, of course, be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much it.

- Glazed and porcelain tile can't be sealed (more than it already is).
- If it's not glazed (like natural stone), look for a product designed specifically for the type.
- Product recommendations are off topic here. Read some labels for what's locally available. Look for reputable brands.

Comment: thanks for the help!  So are there any sealers that you cant remove without grinding out the joint? Ive seen mixed info on '511 impregnator sealer' for example.  I don't want to put something down I cant get out (at least without thinking really hard about putting it down).

Comment: A sealer that doesn't penetrate isn't a sealer, in my opinion. It's a _coating_, and it's likely to be crap in actual performance. You'll have mildewy grout with a shiny finish.

Comment: Ok so if anything is going into the grout, there's probably no reason to take it out? And if application calls for covering tile there's nothing that would 'coat' the tile (since you mention it cant be sealed) without a corresponding solvent that would remove it off the face of the tile (say because it hazes, too sticky, bad appliaiton, or something else)

Answer (score 0):

The substrate below/behind tile is expected to be damp.

This is why there is brush-on membrane, shower tray flashings, waterproof boards, and other sealing products that are installed behind the tiles.

So if you seal moisture in behind the grout sealant it's no big problem. moisture is expected there.

If you're worried about the look perhaps try one of the grout whitening products.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Jasen  I am pretty confident in my install of the Schluter tray and all the waterproofing I did.  I guess it would be more of an aesthetic thing then.   Also I don't want water to be so stagnant in a place that it starts to mold.